# TSQL GROUP BY part of string

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, group-by

I have a simple query.  Something like this:

```
SELECT l.list_name, COUNT(order_id) 
FROM orders o JOIN lists l ON l.order_id=o.order_id 
    WHERE l.list_name LIKE 'orders_1%' or l.list_name LIKE 'orders_2%'
GROUP BY l.list_name
```

The situation looks like this:  overight a stored procedure is updating the lists table, but it chops lists in parts if there are more than 1000 orders.

If I have 1200 orders with criteria or list 'orders_1', then my procedure will create two lists: 'orders_1_1' 'and orders_1_2', the first having 1,000 and second 200 orders.

So when I run my query to count those orders I will get results like so:

```
list_name                  count

orders_1                   100
orders_1_more_than_100_1   1000       
orders_1_more_than_100_2   200
orders_2                   400 
orders_3_1                 1000       
orders_3_2                 1000
orders_3_3                 420  
orders_3_more_than_100_1   1000       
orders_3_more_than_100_2   900
orders_3_more_than_200_1   1000       
orders_3_more_than_200_2   1000
orders_3_more_than_200_3   100      
orders_4                   200
orders_4_more_than_300     200
```

The result I would like to get should look like this:

```
list_name                  count

orders_1                   100
orders_1_more_than_100     1200       
orders_2                   400 
orders_3                   2420 
orders_3_more_than_100     1900 
orders_3_more_than_200     2100     
orders_4                   200 
orders_4_more_than_300     200
```

So that it will sum all lists that start the same.

Any ideas on that? :)

These are the exact values that I have in my list_names column:

```
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_6
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_5_POWYZEJ_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_5_DO_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_4_POWYZEJ_240_5
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_4_POWYZEJ_240_4
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_4_POWYZEJ_240_3
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_4_POWYZEJ_240_2
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_4_POWYZEJ_240_1
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_4_DO_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_3_POWYZEJ_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_3_DO_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_2_POWYZEJ_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_2_DO_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_1
```

What I want is to group them like so:

```
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_6
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_5_POWYZEJ_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_5_DO_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_4_POWYZEJ_240 /*here I must group those 5 lists*/
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_4_DO_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_3_POWYZEJ_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_3_DO_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_2_POWYZEJ_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_2_DO_240
WYS_AUT_PISMO_NR_1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This monstruous expression will isolate string starting from beginning of parameter to last `_` if there are more than one underscores:

```
select case when len (l.list_name) - len (replace (l.list_name, '_', '')) > 1 
            then left(l.list_name, 
                      len (l.list_name) - charindex('_', reverse(l.list_name)))
            else l.list_name
        end
```

Alternatively you might strip 'orders_' from string, replace underscore with dot and convert it to float, then to int to remove decimals, and then back to string using this monstrosity:

```
select 'orders_' + cast (cast (cast (
        replace (substring (@str, 8, 100), '_', '.') 
        as float) as int) as varchar(100))
```

To avoid repeating this blobs, use derived table instead of `lists`:

```
SELECT l.TrimmedListName, COUNT(order_id) 
FROM orders o 
JOIN 
(
   select lists.*,
       -- Remove optional list continuation number
          case when len (list_name) - len (replace (list_name, '_', '')) > 1 
                then left(list_name, 
                          len (list_name) - charindex('_', reverse(list_name)))
                else list_name
            end AS TrimmedListName
     from lists
) l ON l.order_id=o.order_id 
WHERE (l.list_name LIKE 'orders_1%' or l.list_name LIKE 'orders_2%')
GROUP BY l.TrimmedListName
```

Comment: You surprise me every day all over again. Just looking at Your code shows Your skill. You are awesome! I'll try it right away :)

Comment: There is a single problem. If I have 2 lists, lets say: orders_1_more_than_100_1 anf orders_1_more_than_100_2 Your script works fine, but If I have only one list: orders_4 it chops last 2 signs.

Comment: @Misiu I must have misunderstood something because for me it leaves 'orders_4' as it was. Could you please post exact values of list_name column?

Comment: @Misiu I saw your first draft. I'll check with new '_more_than' values.

Comment: @Misiu Could you please change `> 1` to `> 6`? This will leave list_name alone if it has 6 or less underscores.

Answer (score 2):

try something like

```
    select substring(l.list_name, 0, 8), count(order_Id)
    FROM orders o JOIN lists l ON l.order_id=o.order_id  
    WHERE l.list_name LIKE 'orders_1%' or l.list_name LIKE 'orders_2%'        
    group by substring(l.list_name, 0, 8)
```

Updated answer for the updated question:

```
     select newColName, COUNT(order_id)
     from 
     (
          select case when GetSubstringCount(l.list_name, '_', '') > 1 then 
        SUBSTRING(l.list_name, 0, len(l.list_name) - 2)
        else l.list_name end as NewColName
        , order_Id
          FROM orders o JOIN lists l ON l.order_id=o.order_id       
          WHERE l.list_name LIKE 'orders_1%' or l.list_name LIKE 'orders_2%'           
     ) mySubTable 
     group by newColName
```

You'll need something like [This](http://dataeducation.com/counting-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string/) to create the GetSubstringCount method

Comment: I didn't knew that I can group by substring :) I'll check it right away :)

Comment: one more edit. What if I have different length of my list names? I'll edit my question

Comment: Sure, no problem, although I imagine you'll have to just make that substring expression bigger, maybe find the first underscore in the string, then take a length of that underscores position +1

Comment: Ok, that's trickier, you're going to have a big nasty group by expression there

Comment: For a second I was thinking that substring will solve my problem, searching last underscore won't help either :/

Comment: It could be done, but I'd reccomend changing those column names. If you had something unique identifying those _1 and _2 endings it would be so much clearer to the next person that comes along, rather than a big massive group by with replaces / indexof / substring

Comment: @Misiu There, the code isn't as bad as I thought it was, although you'll need a new function to count the underscores

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change anything :/ Lists are chopped into 1k parts because they are used to get addresses and then send packages. This is done every day. So that every person gets it's 1k of orders and addresses. But my report must sum those list and show a total sum for every type.